# Multiple payloads sent to REST api endpoint from Apex Trigger issue

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, class, sandbox

When we create/update a Case  , we send those details/data/payload information to our REST api endpoint via SF developer console using APEX Trigger + Class.

The Case has few lookup/mapping fields to Account, Contact as well as opportunity.

Now , if we create/update ! It systematically updates the fields one-by-one resulting in multiple Trigger invocations which in turn sends multiple payloads to our endpoint.

I understand that's how it works internally.
But is there any possible means to only send 1 payload event to our REST api endpoint with the most upto date information. (Without changing the salesforce internals but only the code or any other means ?)

The below attached image is a scenario where I updated an existing case which in turn invoked the Trigger thrice and send payload to our end thrice.

[image]

Code logic:

Trigger:

```
trigger MyCaseTrigger on Trigger(after insert , after update){

 if(Trigger.isInsert){
 
   String url = "https://www.myendpoint.com/create";
   Wehbook.send(url,Trigger.new,Trigger.old) #handler to send data to my url
}


 if(Trigger.isUpdate){

   
   String url = "https://www.myendpoint.com/update";
   Wehbook.send(url,Trigger.new,Trigger.old) #handler to send data to my url
}


}
```

For now I was able to create a workaround like StateManager.

code logic:

```
StateManger class

Class StateManger{
 public static integer count = 0;
}
```

and updated my trigger like this

Trigger:

```
trigger MyCaseTrigger on Trigger(after insert , after update){
  static integer count = 0 ;
 if(Trigger.isInsert){
 
   if(StateManager.count=0){  
   String url = "https://www.myendpoint.com/create";
Wehbook.send(url,Trigger.new,Trigger.old) #handler to send data to my url
     StateManager.count = StateManager.count +1;
      }
   }


 if(Trigger.isUpdate){
 
   if(StateManager.count == 0){  
   String url = "https://www.myendpoint.com/update";
Wehbook.send(url,Trigger.new,Trigger.old) #handler to send data to myurl
    StateManager.count = StateManager.count +1 

} 
 }


}
```

Webhook apex class :

```
public class Webhook implements HttpCalloutMock {

    public static HttpRequest request;
    public static HttpResponse response;

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        request = req;
        response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }

    public static String jsonContentcreate(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
        String newObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerNew != null) {
           
            newObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerNew);
        }

        String oldObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerOld != null) {
            oldObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerOld);
        }

        String userId = JSON.serialize(UserInfo.getUserId());
  
        
        String content = '{"newCreate": ' + newObjects + ', "oldCreate": ' + oldObjects + ', "userId": ' + userId + '}';
        return content;
    }
    
    
    
        public static String jsonContentupdate(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
        String newObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerNew != null) {
           
            newObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerNew);
        }

        String oldObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerOld != null) {
            oldObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerOld);
        }

        String userId = JSON.serialize(UserInfo.getUserId());
  
        
        String content = '{"newUpdate": ' + newObjects + ', "oldUpdate": ' + oldObjects + ', "userId": ' + userId + '}';
        return content;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(String url, String content) {

        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Webhook());
        }

        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('X-API-KEY', 'myapikey');
        req.setBody(content);
        System.debug('data was sent to lambda');
        h.send(req);
    }

}
```

through this I am able to send data to my endpoint only once and then from my endpoint handler I query back for the case details using ExternalID/ Record ID I obtain.

Is this way of handling the case any good ? Would it harm any functionality in salesforce ?

Comment: One could ask, why do you care if the endpoint is called once on create and again on update?

Comment: Because we need that data for some real-time analytics. 

If an object/record is created as well as updated.

Comment: the general problem you have is that you don't know when the transaction ends. Solutions are going to rely on managing state in the objects (or separate custom objects), async transactions, and some sort of look ahead so you can avoid the separate create + update callouts

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea ...

**During insert (create) event**

- Insert a custom object with two fields: Name (a unique ID - created by a static variable, singleton pattern) + Counter (value = 1)
- Call a future method (or queueable) using the name + counter value (1) + context (like values of the record fields)

**During update event**

- Update the custom object by adding one to the counter
- Call a future method (or queueable) using the name + counter value (2) + context (like values of the record fields)

When the first future runs, it queries the custom object and compares (1) against the value of the custom object counter. If the custom object counter = 2, the future/queueable does nothing. If the custom object counter = 1, then you know that no update was done in the base transaction and can do the callout and delete the custom object

When the second future runs, it queries the custom object and compares (2) against the value of the custom object counter. If the custom object counter <= 2, the future/queueable does the callout and deletes the custom object

If the base transaction is solely an update, then the custom object counter = 1 and the future/queueable is called with name + counter(1). These will match so the callout can occur

Basically, you need to manage state in the base transaction and pass the key to that state into an async transaction that can effectively do a look-ahead and decide if there's more to be done so hold off.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. But I don't understand on how to implement. Can you help me  ? By providing the code. Thank you

Comment: and also do you think with just the code I have posted it would work fine ? In case if concurrently 100 case gets created. 

Will every case have it's own static variable from 0 or all the 100 cases will share the same static variable ?

Comment: you'll need a state per record as a given transaction could have a mix of records that are created, created+updated, or just updated. Also `manager`, not `manger` typo in your class name.  You need to manage state in a persistent database object as the static variable will disappear before the future ever runs. The StateManager is solely there to create UUIDs for the persistent object

Comment: So, either create , create + update and update any of this operations are considered as transaction in salesforce right ? 

Static variables persist across a transaction. 

During create when count is 0 , I send to my endpoint
During create + update when count is 0 , I send to my endpoint 
During update when count is 0, I send to my endpoint 

Is there any way to accomplish what you have said without making any significant changes ?

Comment: static variables persist within the transaction, never across (i,e, the future/queueable can't read them). Your goal is to avoid sending create+update (2 callouts, right?) if the transaction is both a create and an update?

Comment: Yes in that case, I manage the StateManger.count at a trigger level. 

you can see that either for an insert or update command I consider only the count value to be 0. 

The static variable gets incremented only per insert as well as update. 

So, say, 

In this current transaction, if there's insert + update event. Only during insert I send it to my endpoint. With a 30second delay I make a GET case request from my endpoint to salesforce to fetch all the updated details. 

Do you this is this  a good idea ? Do you see this approach failing anywhere ?

Comment: sounds fragile to me - async transactions can consume 60 secs of CPU (longer elapsed). It sounds like you are changing the initial requirements

Comment: No, the ultimate goal is to not send payloads in terms of multiples.
I had another idea of sending data when destructor is invoked but unfortunately there isn't a destructor in apex class and there's is a way to understand when a transaction will end either

Comment: the proxy for when a transaction has ended is when any of its launched async (future/queueable/platform events) start. Hence my answer above

Comment: sounds cool Thank you but it'd pollute the prod. environment :(